# How to hold packets for a short period of time to emulate network lagging?

Tags: python

I'm testing a game under laggy conditions.

When I try this code it just makes the whole connection on my computer freeze :

```
from pydivert import WinDivert
import time

#Filtering ? 
w_outbound = WinDivert("outbound") 

w_outbound.open()

try:
    while True:
        
        outbound_packets = w_outbound.recv()
        time.sleep(0.005)
        w_outbound.send(outbound_packets)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

Theoretically the goal is just to hold the packets for a short period of time to emulate network lagging.I want the filter based on outbound packets.

Here's the doc:

https://pythonhosted.org/pydivert/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never worked with pydivert before but, here's how I would have proceeded:

```
with pydivert.WinDivert() as w:
    for packet in w:
        if packet.is_outbound:
            time.sleep(0.005)
        w.send(packet)
```

Comment: Better than my code but still freeze my whole connection...

Comment: Finally it works I just modified the value because 0.1 or 0.05 were too high

Comment: good to know it worked ! GG GL HF :D What value did you use then ? I also edited the code so that it matches the question sleep value

Comment: tysm! I used 0.00001 instead of 0.005 It's very laggy but it's what I wanted (I think I can take even lower values) but at least I don't have to restart my computer..